# getElementsbyClassName to find and act on all elements

Tags: javascript

Can't quite get this code to enact on all elements within my html - I know [0] means just one - but the code doesn't work without it as its raw js

```
 window.onload = function yourFunction(){
    var str = document.getElementsByClassName('icon')[0].innerHTML;
    
    var res = str.replace(/_s\.png/g, ".png")
   
    document.getElementsByClassName('icon')[0].innerHTML = res;

    setTimeout(yourFunction, 5000);
}

yourFunction();
```

See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6x8jrbr/1/)

I want to it work for all _s instances within the 'icon' classes

Comment: Have your heard of loops?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`. You have to use subscript to access a certain elements, such as looping over to access all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop. To iterate on every element matching your array-like object of elements returned by `getElementsByClassName`.

```
window.onload = function yourFunction(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');
    if (elements){
      for (var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/_s\.png/g, ".png");
      }
    }
    setTimeout(yourFunction, 5000);
}

yourFunction();
```

Comment: Code without explanation doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you, I've added a small explanation on why the `for` is needed.

Comment: What would happen if you remove `if(elements)`?